# Create a CMake project from a directory of source and header files

Tags: cmake

Is there something equivalent to `qmake -project` that will automatically create a CMake project from a directory of source and header files?

Ideally, this should work recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it's an easy project to set up:

```
project(myProject)

enable_language(CXX)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES *.cpp)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(myExe ${SRC_FILES})
```

Assuming you are making an executable. `add_library` should be used if you are making a library. And just change the paths if your project things in subdirectories like `src` and `include`.

Comment: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file Yes, the GLOB option uses simple REGEX.

Comment: Note, this isn't a recommended way of doing it. It is better to manually add the files by hand, but this is a quick and dirty way to do it. If it's for a project that is "done" in the sense you aren't going to be adding/removing source files, then there's no issue.

Comment: Thanks, quick and dirty is fine :) Another question, is it also possible to make it recursive? I have 5-6 sub-folders in the project.

Comment: Read the documentation. There's a GLOB_RECURSE option documented just under the GLOB option.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this was asked quite a while ago, but I'll post my answer anyway, for future reference.)

I think the better idea is not to have a `CMakeLists.txt` that automatically adds all sources with a glob every time it is run, but a static one instead. I guess that what was originally meant was a script that scans the current directory (recursively) for source files and adds them to the CMake file. This could possibly save a lot of time copying the name of every source file to the CMake file. Therefore: Let's automate it!

Create a file named `cmake-project.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# use the first argument as project name
PROJECT_NAME=$1

# find source files, but exclude the build directory
PROJECT_SOURCES=$(find . -iname "*.cpp" -not -path "./build/*") 

# find header files, but exclude the build directory;
# only print the name of the directory; only print unique names
PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=$(find . -iname "*.h" -not -path "./build/*" \
  -printf "%h\n" | sort -u) 

# The standard content of the CMakeLists.txt can be edited here
cat << EOF > CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set(PROJ_NAME      $PROJECT_NAME )
set(PROJ_SOURCES   $PROJECT_SOURCES )

project(\${PROJ_NAME})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(\${PROJ_NAME} \${PROJ_SOURCES})
EOF
```

Then, make the file executable with `chmod +x cmake-project.sh`. Now you can run `./cmake-project.sh [your_project_name]` in the root directory to create a static (i.e. without glob) `CMakeLists.txt` automatically.

Of course you'll have to adapt things if necessary (e.g. use `.cc` instead of `.cpp`), but you get the idea.